# Let $f$ and $g$ be uniformly continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f - g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Idea: In order to prove $f-g$ is uniformly continuous, we need to show for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, s.t for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, $|(f-g)(x)-(f-g)(y)|<\epsilon$. Therefore
$|(f-g)(x)-(f-g)(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)-g(x)+g(y)|$

Am I on the right track? How can I prove this?

Comment: that would be the easy case if the formulas for $f$ and $g$ were explicit; hint: do you have any previous results you are allowed to use? perhaps theorems about the continuity of compositions, product, addition and so on of the continuous functions being continuous? (that would be the easiest route)

Answer (score 2):

You're close. We choose instead $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|g(x) - g(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. We then apply triangle inequality:
$$
\begin{align*}
|(f-g)(x) - (f-g)(y)| &= |(f(x) - f(y)) - (g(x) - g(y))| \\
&\leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |g(x) - g(y)| \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$